# Does planets revolves around all the 88 constellations?

Tags: solar-system

I am a beginner / novice and I have got very little knowledge about astronomy

Please tell me whether 'Planets' revolves around all the 80+ constellations or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13086

Comment: Planets (for the most part) revolve around individual suns. A constellation is just a group of stars that are in the same part of the sky - as viewed from Earth. So the question, as written, really just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Planets does not go through all the constellations.

The path the Sun and the planets (approximately) follows is called the [ecliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic). The constellation this line goes through is known as the [Zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zodiac), but the current number is actually 13.

A star map, with the ecliptic drawn:

[image: star map]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Can you post a better image of this?  Could not read out what's written over there?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Hipparcos_Catalogue_equirectangular_plot.svg is a larger version of this image. Note the image is SVG and can thus be theoretically expanded to any size.