# Order of shells formed in a massive star

Tags: stellar-evolution

In addition to the question with the picture [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44430/do-elements-like-magnesium-and-sulfur-form-an-layer-on-massive-stars), why do shells don't form the same order as the [alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_process#:%7E:text=The%20alpha%20process%2C%20also%20known,only%20helium%2C%20and%20produces%20carbon.&text=Silicon%20and%20calcium%20are%20purely%20alpha%20process%20elements.)?
[image]

image credit: Gemini Observatory/NSF/C.Aspin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a reasonable section on this in the wikipedia pages on [Neon-burning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon-burning_process) and [oxygen-burning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen-burning_process#Pre-oxygen_burning) if you can extract the relevant information.

Oxygen-16 is a really stable, "doubly-magic" nucleus, in that it contains complete shells of both protons and neutrons. The addition of an alpha particle through fusion with a He nucleus doesn't occur quite so easily for Oxygen-16 as it does for adding an alpha particle to Neon-20.

In fact "oxygen-burning" occurs most readily by combining an oxygen nucleus with another oxygen nucleus, partly I guess because the He nuclei get vacuumed up by reactions with carbon and neon first. As a result, the Coulomb barrier is much higher for oxygen-burning and it needs high temperatures than neon-burning. Thus the oxygen-burning and neon-burning shells appear "out of order" compared with how you might think they would be.