# How well defined are the elemental shells in evolved stars?

Tags: stellar-evolution, stellar-astrophysics

Most textbooks and popular science show highly evolved massive stars with an onion-like structure with layers or shells of different elements fusing. This is clearly approximate (as [noted in the comments here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44430/do-elements-like-magnesium-and-sulfur-form-a-layer-inside-massive-stars?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but *how* *approximate* is it?

It would seem to me that even in a non-convective environment there would be significant diffusion over stellar timescales that would mix the layers, perhaps into a soft distribution with higher probability of finding heavy elements deeper. But what does actual models and simulations say?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this figure form [Hirschi, Meynet, Maeder (2004)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004A%26A...425..649H/abstract)

[image: abundance of elements inside a star]

They are simulating the internal structure of the star and studying its evolution in the pre-supernova phase. This figure refers to a non rotating star of $M=20M_\odot$ at the end of the Silicon burning stage. It shows the relative abundance of the elements as a function of the lagrangian mass coordinate.

In this figure, the shells are not as clear-cut as in the cartoon in the question you cite, but it is easy to identify a sequence of shells nonetheless.

The sequence I see here is Ni - Si/S - O - O/Ne - O/C - He - H/He

If you go and look at the paper itself, there are many more figures like this one, referring to rotating stars and to different burning stages.